# Ethernet MAC Controller IC design process

Tags: integrated-circuit, ethernet, rtl, chip-design, mac

I'm from an embedded software background, and I am trying to learn more about chip design. To this end I want to understand what goes into designing and implementing a digital IC like an ethernet controller (e.g. [Microchip's KSZ8851](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/ksz8851))

I've been researching and starting to read some Digital Design and CMOS/VLSI textbooks, and so far, here is what I think would be the process (for this specific example at least):

1. Become an expert or build a solid understanding of the 802.3 standard
   to be able to come up with a specification and functional block
   diagram of the digital components involved in realizing the functions of the
   data link layer (and the media-dependent physical layer if
   incorporating PHY also)
2. Create a HDL description of the design in a language like Verilog (RTL design and
   functional verification steps)
3. Use EDA tools to translate RTL into physical design - synthesis to
   netlist all the way to tape-out, and finally send to foundry for
   fabrication followed by post-silicon validation.

Is my understanding correct so far?

I do realize the whole process is probably way more complex than this, but are these roughly the steps that commercial chip makers follow, say the Microchip engineers that made KSZ8851?

Also are there examples of MAC cores out there one can learn from that more closely mirror commercial production? I did find some open-source MAC IP cores summarized here (https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijrc/2023/9222318/)

Comment: It doesn't directly answer your question about design of an Ethernet MAC controller, but have you seen [TinyTapeout is an educational project that makes it easier and cheaper than ever to get your digital designs manufactured on a real chip!](https://tinytapeout.com/). While [How big can my design be?](https://tinytapeout.com/faq/#how-big-can-my-design-be) says ``This is enough for about 1000 digital logic gates, depending on their size`` which probably isn't large enough for an Ethernet MAC using the TinyTapeout tools to design an actual ASIC could be a useful learning exercise.

Answer (score 3):

> Is my understanding correct so far?

Yes, that is a good high-level description of the IC design process.

Here are a couple of points to emphasize:

- *Teams* of engineers are employed to design such chips.
- Chips often consist of design blocks which are reused from previous chips.

To the 1st point, no single engineer is expected to be an expert in all the implementation details of all components of a chip.  Design engineers rely heavily on application engineers for guidance in understanding how to implement the MAC protocol.  Designers also work closely in tandem with verification engineers who independently create tests according to the design spec.

Also, looking at the functional block diagram of one of the datasheets from your Microchip link, there are a variety of different types of blocks: PLL, voltage regulator, LED driver, EEPROM interface, etc.  This underscores the need for a *team* of experts.

To the second point, many chips leverage designs from previous chips in order to save time and money.  Small design blocks may be designed from scratch, but larger designs typically are reused as-is, or previous versions are used as starting points for the new chip.

Alternately, it is common for companies to purchase some design blocks as intellectual property (IP) from other companies (IP providers).  This is a cost trade-off; while your company will expend a lot of money to purchase the IP, it will allow the chip to hit the market sooner to beat the competition.  So, knowledge of the details of the design implementation are not required by members of the design team.

Comment: Some IC manufacturers may also use IP from other companies. E.g. the Texas Instruments [AM572x Sitara Processor Technical Reference Manual (Rev. L)](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/spruhz6) has in section _24.7 SuperSpeed USB DRD_ ``NOTE: ... For those who do wish to substantially modify the existing Linux USB driver(s), or create new drivers, contact TI for more information on how to obtain the third party documentation under NDA.``, which I think is because TI licensed the USB 3.0 controller IP from a different company.

Answer (score 1):

A PHY is very much an analog affair. Analog and Digital IC design are almost separate disciplines, with a rather narrow shared base of knowledge. The particular chip you refer to - KSZ8851 - has a 125Ms/s DAC and ADC inside, for example.

I'd stay well within the digital realm in the beginning and use an external PHY, or at least use an external ADC and DAC (8 bits is more than enough). CMOS ADC and DAC design alone fits into a couple of sizable books worth of material.

The minimally viable 10/100 MAC is a fairly simple affair, so can be a good starting point.

To understand how they really work, I'd suggest getting a Raspberry Pico. There's a rudimentary 100M MAC design for it that fit in its PIO block. A minimal digital "glue block" external to an MCU would need similar functionality, but reimplemented in a PLD or discrete logic. The latter is entirely possible for a minimal 100M MAC, but not necessarily cost-friendly.

Once you add other functionality, like request buffers, CRC, SPI interface, IP offload, you'll have a larger design that won't fit into a CPLD anymore, and will need an FPGA.

The HDL you got running on an FPGA can be in many cases sent to a semiconductor house to run a synthesis and test benches on, and get a tapeout.

I'd get a Raspberry Pico first since it's a useful gadget, and hook a PHY to it, then get a small FPGA board with a PHY already on it. That way you can play with PIO ("I/O offload") on the RP2040 chip, and then move to an FPGA.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will look into getting the Pico and starting with a minimal design.